# Can I use C# OrderBy of linq in CodeHunt

Tags: c#

[Problem Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJsN0.jpg)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public static class Program {
    public static int[] Puzzle(int[] a) {
    return a.OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();
    }
}
```

[My code and wrong information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2m10.png)
**Bad Dependency

[System.Core]System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1**

Why I am wrong？Whether or not the platform can support OrderBy？Do I need a custom sort function？The code can run successful in VS2015, I have tried.

www.codehunt.com

Comment: Have you tried `Array.Sort`?

Comment: I downvoted this question because you should always supply code and error messages as text, not images (otherwise elements of your question can not be searched and this question has no further use to the wider community). Edit your question. Add the code.

Comment: Can you use `OrderBy()`? Apparently not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try follow.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public static class Program {
    public static int[] Puzzle(int[] a) 
    {
          return Array.Sort(a);
    }
}
```